# Trying to capture categories field type data in user profile save/update

Tags: plugin-development, categories, field, usermodel

I am trying to capture the data that is selected when a user selects categories within a categories field type (handle: groups) within the Control Panel profile tab.

I was looking thru the Fields, Categories and Content services documentation in the craft docs section and I am still unsure.

I noticed when I did a var_dump of $user:

```
$user = UserModel::populateModel(UserRecord::model()->findById($id));
```

It displays the field 'groups' within the _attributeConfigs, but does not show up in private '_attributes' (Craft\BaseModel)

The other fields do show up, for example, occupation shows up within both the _attributeConfigs (its a string) and shows up in private '_attributes' (Craft\BaseModel) with a value of 'Teacher'.

I am unsure how to get the data the user selected when selecting the categories while updating their profile within the control panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, its very easy to pull data from a relational fieldtype (Categories, Entries, Assets etc). E.g. if your Categories field handle is `memberGroups`, you can simply do this:

```
$categories = $user->memberGroups;
```

However, your Categories field handle is `groups`, which conflicts with the built-in UserModel attribute `groups`, used to pull any user groups the user is a member of – this means that calling `$user->groups` will give you an array of UserGroupModel instances, ignoring your Categories field.

Also, the `$user->getContent()->getAttribute('groups');` method doesn't appear to work for relational fields.

The easy answer: I'd suggest you simply change the field handle for your Categories field to something else – for example `memberGroups`. Don't worry, you won't lose any data if you do. Then you can just do `$categories = $user->memberGroups;`.

**If you can't or wont change the field handle, here's a workaround:**

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
$criteria->relatedTo = array(
    'sourceElement' => $user,
    'field' => 'groups'
);
$categories = $criteria->find();
```

Comment: Hi Mats - Sorry for confusing you, the "groups" is the handle of a custom category field type I assigned to the users field within the CP users settings fields page (/admin/settings/users/fields). Your code returns the user groups  that were created at /admin/settings/users, if the user w/ that id is assigned any of those groups. I am looking for the custom field type: "groups"

Comment: If I do: $user->getContent()->occupation; it shows the occupation (is custom field type plain text) field data entered. But If I do $user->getContent()->groups; its blank. The groups field shows up within Craft\ContentModel Object
(
    [_requiredFields:Craft\ContentModel:private] => 
    [_attributeConfigs:Craft\ContentModel:private] => Array

Comment: It prints out the group in that array:

            [groups] => Array
                (
                    [model] => 
                    [column] => text
                    [type] => mixed
                    [label] => Groups
                )

Comment: I can get the info if I do a query of something like: select craft_content.title from craft_relations where sourceId = $id join craft_content on craft_relations.targetId = craft_content.elementId; But I want to do this using the craft services provided.

Comment: Aaah, right... You're absolutely correct, `$user->groups` will output any groups (UserGroupModels) the user is in. If your field had a different handle, e.g. `groupCategories`, my original answer would work (i.e. `$user->groupCategories`). It's actually a bit weird that Craft allows `groups` as a field handle; pretty much every other built-in attribute for any of the element models is a reserved word and can't be used for field handles. Maybe this is an oversight on P&T's behalf, you might want to shoot them an email at support@craftcms.com.

Comment: @Brad Just edited my answer, including a workaround if you don't want to change the field handle. Hope it works out!